# Java doesn't seem to match regex despite input being true

Tags: java, regex, debugging, hashmap, pattern-matching

long time user but new poster, I am having a very frustrating problem which I can't seem to debug. I have a program performing a phonetic search for a theoretical exercise. The inputs are received via standard input.
So,

```
Java MyAppication Jones Smith Andrews < NAMES.TXT
```

From there, the search terms are pushed into a Hashmap and the NAMES.TXT is also pushed into the HashMap. An operation is performed on the values that strips certain characters such as vowels.

For example: Jones is stored in the Directory Hashmap as Directory["Jones"] = Jns
The same is done for the search terms hash map.

This is the search method,

```
  private static String search(){
  Iterator<String> searchKeyIterator = search.keySet().iterator(); 
  Iterator<String> directoryKeyIterator = directory.keySet().iterator(); 
  String output = new String();

  //Loop through the search terms
  while(searchKeyIterator.hasNext()){
      String searchkey = searchKeyIterator.next(); 
      Pattern searchRegex = Pattern.compile(regexBuild(search.get(searchkey))); 

      output += "\n" + searchkey + ": ";

      while(directoryKeyIterator.hasNext()){
          String directorykey = directoryKeyIterator.next();

          Matcher m  = searchRegex.matcher(directory.get(directorykey));
          boolean b = m.matches();

          if(b == true){
              output += directorykey + ", ";

          }
      }

      output = output.substring(0, output.length() - 2);
  }
    return output;}
```

It works by looping through the search directory and forming a regex pattern for each term (this is because of the constraints placed on equivalent characters). This regex is then matched against the directory.

For example the input of Jones becomes Jns, the regex for this becomes [CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz][MNmn][CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz] which means Anything that matches JNS, SNS, Cng would match this.

However, it doesn't seem to match.
This is the data set as stored

```
key: Smith value: Smt
key: Johnson  value: Jnsn
key: Ericsson  value: Ercssn
key: Smyth value: Smt
key: Macdonald  value: Mcdnld
key: Smid  value: Smd
key: Schmidt  value: Scmdt
key: Smithers  value: Smtrs
key: Jonas  value: Jns
key: Nest O'Malett  value: Nst Mltt
key: Smythe  value: Smt
key: Van Damme value: Vn Dmm
key: Erikson  value: Erksn
key: Saunas  value: Sns
key: Johns  value: Jns
```

BUT the results seem to state that there is no match despite seeing that there is one from the list.

```
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=[CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz][MNmn][CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz] region=0,3 lastmatch=]
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=[CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz][MNmn][CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz] region=0,5 lastmatch=]
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=[CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz][MNmn][CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz] region=0,7 lastmatch=]
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=[CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz][MNmn][CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz] region=0,3 lastmatch=]
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=[CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz][MNmn][CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz] region=0,7 lastmatch=]
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=[CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz][MNmn][CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz] region=0,4 lastmatch=]
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=[CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz][MNmn][CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz] region=0,6 lastmatch=]
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=[CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz][MNmn][CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz] region=0,6 lastmatch=]
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=[CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz][MNmn][CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz] region=0,4 lastmatch=]
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=[CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz][MNmn][CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz] region=0,9 lastmatch=]
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=[CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz][MNmn][CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz] region=0,4 lastmatch=]
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=[CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz][MNmn][CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz] region=0,6 lastmatch=]
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=[CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz][MNmn][CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz] region=0,6 lastmatch=]
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=[CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz][MNmn][CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz] region=0,4 lastmatch=]
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=[CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz][MNmn][CGJKQSXYZcgjkqsxyz] region=0,4 lastmatch=]
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you printed out `directory.get(directorykey)` to see what it is?

Comment: Yes, it would seem there is some white space at the end of my directory inputs. So Jns is actually "Jns ". I'll try for that now and see if it resolves my issue.